# TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, tkinter

This code will run a basic data input window through `tkinter` which will save the user's inputs. When i run the code and mouse click the Submit button I get the error:

```
print ("Información Adicional: {}".format(self.entry_name.get(1.0, "end")))

TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

This is the code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class ImprintPlusApp:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_header.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, text = "Bienvenidos a Imprint Plus Manager")

        self.frame_crearorden = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_crearorden.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Nombre").grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Email").grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Numero Cel/Tel").grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 5)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Información Adicional").grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 5)

        self.entry_name = ttk.Entry(self.frame_crearorden, width = 24)
        self.entry_email = ttk.Entry(self.frame_crearorden, width = 24)
        self.entry_numtc = ttk.Entry(self.frame_crearorden, width = 24)
        self.entry_addinf = Text(self.frame_crearorden, width = 50, height = 10)

        self.entry_name.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_email.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_numtc.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_addinf.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5)

        ttk.Button(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Submit", command = self.submit).grid(row = 8, column = 1,columnspan = 1, padx = 5)
        ttk.Button(self.frame_crearorden, text = "Clear", command = self.clear).grid(row = 8, columnspan = 1, padx = 5)

    def submit(self):
        print ("Nombre: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Email: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Num Cel/Tel: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Información Adicional: {}".format(self.entry_name.get(1.0, "end")))
        self.clear()
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Orden #", message = "Orden Guardada")

    def clear(self):
        self.entry_name.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_email.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_numtc.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_addinf.delete(1.0, "end")


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = ImprintPlusApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What is happening with the `get()` function that causes this error?

Comment: `Entry.get` is **not** the same as `dict.get`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do, but this is the line causing the error, as clearly indicated by the error message -

```
print ("Información Adicional: {}".format(self.entry_name.get(1.0, "end")))
```

You need to do -

```
print ("Información Adicional: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
```

Because Tkinter.Entry class' `get()` function does not take any arguments.

Also looking at the code, there seems to be a logical issue -

```
def submit(self):
        print ("Nombre: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Email: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Num Cel/Tel: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Información Adicional: {}".format(self.entry_name.get(1.0, "end")))
```

Don't you want to get each entry from different `Entry` objects? Like this -

```
def submit(self):
        print ("Nombre: {}".format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print ("Email: {}".format(self.entry_email.get()))
        print ("Num Cel/Tel: {}".format(self.entry_numtc.get()))
        print ("Información Adicional: {}".format(self.entry_addinf.get()))
```

Comment: This solved my main issue. I can't believe I made such a logical blunder with the entry objects, I guess it was coding at 4 a.m. .I'm very grateful sir!